Unable to connect to firefox debugging protocol on widows
I am having issues trying to extract the urls of the open tabs in firefox
I am trying to extract a list of urls of open tabs in firefox by attempting to leverage firefox debugging protocol. NOTE, I have set the following in firefox:
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled to true, I have also set devtools.debugger.remote-websocket to true, and I have confirmed that the port is the right one in firefox via devtools.debugger.remote-port, I have attempted switching to a different port too, however, this error keep popping up whenever I run the script hinting that firefox or the windows machine is probably blocking the connection. Other browsers don't seem to have this issue:
 dial tcp [::1]:9222: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
here is the go script
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

type firefoxTab struct {
    URL string `json:"url"`
}

type firefoxResponse struct {
    Tabs []firefoxTab `json:"tabs"`
}

func main() {
    // Connect to firefox
    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to Firefox remote debugging: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // Send the JSON request to retrieve the list of tabs
    if err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(`{"to":"root","type":"listTabs"}`)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send request: %v", err)
    }

    // Read the response
    _, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read response: %v", err)
    }

    // Parse the JSON response
    var response firefoxResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(msg, &response); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse JSON response: %v", err)
    }

    // Print the URLs of all open tabs
    for _, tab := range response.Tabs {
        fmt.Println(tab.URL)
    }
}


